# RxSwift - Split up sequence into smaller sequences to concat on

Tags: ios, swift, concatenation, rx-swift

**Background**

I am trying to implement downloading a file via chunks using the `Range` header.

**Goal**

I would like to take a large sequence of http requests into four sequences that I can then concat to process 4 requests at a time.

**Current Standing**

I am currently taking my sequence and using `concat` to ensure that the first request observable is completed before I start the second. This was done to ensure that I do not overload Alamofire with too many requests and thus end up with requests that time out.

Ideally I would like to divide my sequence into four fairly equal sequences since Alamofire is set up to handle four connections to the host at a time. I want to do this because I believe it would increase my download speeds.

**Downloading File Using Chunks**

```
Observable.generate(initialState: 0, condition: { $0 < fileSize }, iterate: {$0 + self.defaultChunkSize})
    .map( { (startChunk) in
        let endChunk = startChunk + self.defaultChunkSize > fileSize ? fileSize : startChunk + self.defaultChunkSize

        return (startChunk, endChunk)
    })
    .map({ (startChunk: Int, endChunk: Int) -> Observable<FileChunkResult> in
        self.filesClient.downloadChunkOf(fileId: file.id, startChunk: Int64(startChunk), endChunk: Int64(endChunk))
    })

    .concat() // <----- This is where I am forcing the large sequence to do one observable at a time

    .flatMap( { (result: FileChunkResult) -> Observable<FileSaveChunkResult> in
        switch (result) {
        case FileChunkResult.success(let chunkData):
            return self.saveChunkToFile(fileChunk: chunkData, location: urlToSaveTo)
        case FileChunkResult.failure: // Maybe change this to just default and return Observable.just(FileSaveChunkResult.failure)
            break
        case FileChunkResult.parserError:
            break
        }

        return Observable.just(FileSaveChunkResult.failure)
    })
    .flatMap( { (result: FileSaveChunkResult) -> Observable<Progress> in
        switch (result) {
        case FileSaveChunkResult.success(let bytesSaved):
            progress.completedUnitCount += bytesSaved
        case FileSaveChunkResult.failure:
            break
        }

        return Observable.just(progress)
    })
```

Comment: Just an FYI. (1) There is nothing in AlamoFire that restricts you to four requests at a time, although there might be something about your server that causes such a restriction. (2) It is unlikely that four requests uploading in parallel at 1/4 maximum speed each will complete faster than four request uploading sequentially at full speed each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will break up the chunks into four equal size arrays which use concat to ensure that only one save from each array is active at a time. This means that you will consistently have 4 `saveChunkToFile` calls active any any one moment no matter how fast or slow any particular call is.

In other words, it starts up four requests immediately and then starts one request every time one of the previous requests is complete.

```
let generator = Observable.generate(initialState: 0, condition: { $0 < fileSize }, iterate: { $0 + defaultChunkSize })
let chunks  = generator.map( { (startChunk) -> (Int64, Int64) in
    let endChunk = (startChunk + defaultChunkSize > fileSize ? fileSize : startChunk + defaultChunkSize )
    return (startChunk, endChunk)
})

let count = ceil(Double(fileSize) / Double(defaultChunkSize) / 4)
let requests = chunks.window(timeSpan: 0.0, count: Int(count), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .flatMap { $0
        .map( { (startChunk: Int64, endChunk: Int64) -> Observable<FileChunk> in
            return makeChunkRequest(url: downloadUrl, startChunk: startChunk, endChunk: endChunk)
        }).concat()
}

let downloadObservable = requests
    .flatMap( { (fileChunk: FileChunk) -> Observable<FileSaveChunkResult> in
        return saveChunkToFile(fileChunk: fileChunk, location: localDestinationUrl)
    }).flatMap( { (saveResult: FileSaveChunkResult) -> Observable<Progress> in
        if case .success(let bytesSaved) = saveResult {
            progress.completedUnitCount += bytesSaved
        }
        return Observable.just(progress)
    })

_ = downloadObservable.subscribe(onNext: { print(Date(), $0) })
```